# How to get React button's click events and class name from vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app, react-dom

I'm curious if there's a way to get React's click events and button className from vanilla JS in index.html script tag?

So here's my ***index.html*** file from create-react-app. I've added my vanilla JS code in script tag.

```
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
  </body>
```

and here's ***myscript.js***

```
var myBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("click-button");
var alertNow = function() {
   alert('hello world')
}
for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
    myBtn[i].addEventListener('click', alertNow, false);
};
```

and inside my React's ***App.js***, I've added the button with className 'click-button'...
But when I click on the button, it doesn't do anything.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <button className="click-button">Click Me</button>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I make this work? The script tag works well when I use it on plain html project.. but it looks like it can't get events from React?

I'd appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add event listeners to the button which is not rendered yet. i.e. You are executing your script too early.

**So use `load`** in your script

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  var myBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("click-button");
  var alertNow = function() {
    alert("hello world");
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
    myBtn[i].addEventListener("click", alertNow, false);
  }
});
```

Also in your html, make sure to use [defer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

```
...
<script defer src="myscript.js"></script>
...
```

See [Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-pare-t00xm?file=/public/myscript.js)

Answer (score 1):

Your script is running before the react button exists.  You want to call your script after react has completed it’s first render.

Wrap the code in `myscript` with a function then call that in the `useEffect` hook.

`myscript.js`

```js
function run() {
var myBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("click-button");
var alertNow = function() {
   alert('hello world')
}
for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
    myBtn[i].addEventListener('click', alertNow, false);
};
}
```

`app.js`

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
useEffect(()=>{
// call the function from myscript
run()
},[])
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <button className="click-button">Click Me</button>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```